# How to check when column value change from 0 to 1 and after many count column 1 and column 2 values are same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have one dataframe with column x and column y , I want to check when column x value changes from 0 to 1 and count column y value change from 0 to 1 after how many rows after x changes from 0 to 1

```
here is my dataframe;

df1=pd.DataFrame({'x':[0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1],'y':[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1]})

desired_output

df_out=pd.DataFrame({'count_delay':[1,3,0]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `diff`

```
id1 = df1.index[df1.x.diff().eq(1)]
id2 = df1.index[df1.y.diff().eq(1)]
id2-id1
Int64Index([1, 3, 0], dtype='int64')
```

For groupby

```
df1.groupby(df1.x.diff().eq(1).cumsum()).y.apply(lambda x : x.index[x.diff().eq(1)]-x.index.min())
x
0     Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
1    Int64Index([1], dtype='int64')
2    Int64Index([3], dtype='int64')
3     Int64Index([], dtype='int64')
Name: y, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution , here i am trying to get only first change group so i changed your code little bit and run for my data , id1 = df1.index[df1.x.diff().eq(1)][0] and giving error index 0 of bound , maybe in data never change value from 0 to 1 so there is empty index , how to avoid this error ?

Comment: @Nickel update , you can just drop the first index of output